# How to hide empty fields on user accounts display?

Tags: entities

Let's say a profile2 has 3 fields.

```
Weight: 
Height:
Length:
```

The user only inputs 45 kg and 160 cm, **BUT** for length he inputs nothing.

Now the display is like this:

```
Weight:45kg
Height:160cm
Length:Select
```

How can I hide the field that had no input like this:

```
Weight:45kg
Height:160cm
```

Since the user didn't select any value for length, and it's not a required field. I don't want it displayed on the user profile.

I know this can be done with Views and no results behavior, but I need this for user profile display.

Here is a live example:

http://vuxi.com/users/nitap

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about the modules and field types you are using, as well as how these are being rendered / printed on the theme layer? Drupal by default will not show empty fields, so something else must be printing these values.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this use node.tpl for this node type and add a php check like the following:

```
 <?php if(!empty($content['your_field_name'])): ?>
    <div class="field-label"><strong><?php echo t('Your Label'); ?></strong></div>
    <?php print render($content['Your field Name']); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In custom module or `template.php` add:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables){
  if(!isset($variables['user_profile']['field_drinking']['und'][0]['value'])){
  unset($variables['user_profile']['field_drinking']);
}
```

Replace `THEMENAME` with your themename or modulename if defined in module.

The condition may not be the right one bicause I don't know if the value is not set as `Select`. But I am sure that you get the Idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work was because I added the "Select" field to replace the default "-None-". The default must be kept to "none" and changed via hook_form_alter instead.